# Installing SQL Server 2012 - Error: Prior Visual Studio 2010 instances requiring update

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition and I can get to the point where it's doing the Installation Rule Checks but one of the rules keep failing:

'Prior Visual Studio 2010 instances requiring update'

It basically indicates that I need to have VS2010 SP1 installed. However, I DO have VS2010 SP1 installed. I've tried reapplying the VS2010 SP1 and installing the VS2010 patches on the SQL Server 2012 media as well to no avail.

Is anyone else seeing this issue? Have any ideas that I could try?

Answer (score 51):

I had this issue too, after following [this guide](http://sqlserver-help.com/2011/12/08/help-getting-visual-studio-service-pack-error-while-installing-sql-server-2012-release-candidate-0-rc0/), it was simply 1 additional patch that was required to get past the

> Rule "Prior Visual Studio 2010 instances requiring update." failed.

Was to locate this file, and patch my machine

> VS10sp1-KB983509.msp

Simply do a file search on the installation media for SQL Server 2012, in my case it was in \redist\VisualStudioShell (whereas in the guide it's listed as being in a different location).

Then hit 're-run'.

[image: Failed State]

Comment: I used SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe file to install sql server 2012. When I double clicked it, it unzipped files under c:\abfe04dc... directory. I found vs10sp1-kb983509.msp file in this directory. I simply installed.

Comment: Worked for me too.

Since the VS2010 Service pack is no longer available for download from Microsoft, the next best thing is to download SQLEXPRWT_64_ENU.exe (which *is* still available); Launch it; wait for the installer to extract the contents to a temporary directory in C:\ and then find, and run the patch. After installing vs10sp1-kb983509.msp I killed the SQLEXPRWT_64_ENU.exe process. Killing the process 'cleaned up' the temporary directory. Good suggestion.

Comment: In my case i have to search VisualStudioShell folder inside "this PC". It took time but when i found it. I located and installed VS10sp1-KB983509.msp. After that this problem was solved for me. THANKS

Answer (score 31):

there are two way:

First :

Inside your `CD` of `SQL Server 2012`

you can go to this path `\redist\VisualStudioShell`.

And you most install this file `VS10sp1-KB983509.msp`.

After several minutes your problem fix.

Restart your computer and then fire `SetUp` of `SQL Server 2012`.

See this picture.

[image]

Secound :

But if you want download online `Service Pack 1` view [This Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)

And press download.

After download run this exe file and let it download and fix your VS2010 to VS2010 SP1.

And then restart your windows.

After this operation you can install `SQL Server 2012`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to install SQL server 2014 and same story happened. I had installed both VS2010 and VS2015 before. I tried all solutions where provided nothing worked.At last If you have new versions of VS like VS2015 or VS2017, uninstall VS2010 (if you really don't need it ).

If you want to have VS2010 on your system, install SQL server first and then install VS2010.When SQL server is installing it uses an instance of VS2010, if you have installed VS2010 before and that is an old version this error happens.

Comment: I uninstalled VS2010, and that solved the issue. I'm thankful for your solution since it gave me the idea to try uninstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem installing SQL Server 2014. Turns out it was due to a **Windows Phone toolkit** that I had installed back in 2010. If you run into this, make sure you **uninstall any Windows phone stuff that isn't current.**

I figured it out by looking at the log, which can be found by clicking "Detailed Report," which opens an HTML file. The file path is conveniently displayed within the HTML page. Open the directory that the file is in and look for "Detail.txt." Then search for the word "fail."

In my case there was a line showing **WP_[something]** as "Installed." I searched for the WP_ item and came across some blog posts about trouble uninstalling Windows Phone toolkits.

When I attempted to uninstall the windows phone I ran into more trouble. The uninstaller wanted to install three packages instead of uninstalling the toolkit. Eventually found this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/07/12/10037442.aspx linking to this XNA cleanup tool: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/04/10/9544320.aspx.

I ran the cleanup tool and finally SQL Server installer passed the check and allowed me to install. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Only install the Service Pack (VS10sp1-KB983509.msp) wasn't enough to me.

I had to uninstall the Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010 to continue the installation :)

Answer (score -1):

I did everything provided in the previous answers to this question, but still had the issue. I did have the update installed, but I ran the installer again, reapplying the update while SQL 2012 Installer was open on the screen where I could run the check again. After it finished, I ran the check again and it passed.