# Error: Prior Visual Studio 2010 instances requiring update during SQL Server 2012 installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2012 Management Studio and during the process, one of the rules keep failing:

> 'Prior Visual Studio 2010 instances requiring update'

When I try to install the patch from `"redist\VisualStudioShell"` it rolls back. Any help please?

This is the only solution i have found till now to install the **VS10sp1-KB983509.msp** update but keps rolling back.

**I repeat the solution to this problem is, suggested to install the update package,which i am unable to install as it keeps rolling back. So any help guys rather than just marking it as duplicate.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing SQL Server 2012 - Error: Prior Visual Studio 2010 instances requiring update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589107/installing-sql-server-2012-error-prior-visual-studio-2010-instances-requiring)

Comment: @TheGameiswar the post is suggesting to install update package, which i have tried but the installation keeps rolling back, so probably it is not duplicate. Dont you agree ?

Comment: there is also a second step in second answer,did you tried that?.also can you check for any info in eventvwr and installation log

Comment: yes i did, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Just had same problem a while ago.
The patch might just missing a privilege.

I was able to proceed with this.

1. run cmd as administrator
2. locate and run VS10sp1-KB983509.msp

   ```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>F:

    F:\>cd redist

    F:\redist>cd VisualStudioShell

    F:\redist\VisualStudioShell>VS10sp1-KB983509.msp
   ```

I hope that could help.